# extends GraphicsProgram

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics

I'm watching the Programming Methodology from Stanford on Youtube and professor uses the GraphicsProgram as a basic class for the class he creates.

I do:

```
public class Test extends GraphicsProgram {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }
}
```

But getting the error that GraphicsProgram can't be resolved to a type.

I clicked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> being in Eclipse to import required packages but nothing happened.

Just wondered how professor uses it, please tell me if you know, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be from an ACM JTF (Java Task Force) library.  A google search for GraphicsProgram.java should help you out.  It looks like the source code is available here: http://jtf.acm.org/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the `GraphicsProgram` class from the [Java Task Force](http://jtf.acm.org/) library?

**Edit:** Looks like they've got they rolled [their own Eclipse distribution](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/software/) too. It'll probably be easier just to use that.